# Justify-between is not working on tailwind

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to add justify-between between the hello and the user image & name, they are in different divs but its still not doing much. i tried multiple ways but i can't seem to get it. Im fairly new so any advice will help

this is what i currently have right now

[sorry for the bad drawing but you get the point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx05t.png)

```
import Layout from "@/components/layout";
import {useSession} from "next-auth/react";

export default function Home() {
  const {data: session} = useSession();
  return <Layout>
  <div>
    <div className="text-blue-900 flex justify-between">
      <h2>
        Hello, {session?.user?.name}
      </h2>
      <div className="flex bg-gray-300 gap-1 text-black">
      <img src={session?.user?.image} alt="" className="w-8 h-8"/>
        <span className="py-1 px-2">
        {session?.user?.name}
        </span>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
</Layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe parent div is limiting the flex div to take up entire line, consequently your div have no enough space for the space between elements.

Try to add w-full class on div right after Layout component to test it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the width of the parent? I think the issue is coming from the fact that the parent width is too small